# 1999 s10 radiator?, running, coolant system problems

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, radiator, s10, coolant-leak

Ok, we'll start from the beginning. I saw smoke coming out from under the hood so I opened the hood.  There was coolant passing out a very small pen hole in the top right corner of my radiator.  I bought a repair kit specially designed for my problem applied it exactly as it said.  I waited more then the time stated, and filled the radiator back up.  It seemed to be able to hold water and pressure without leaking.

I then drove 10 miles and stopped, however when I stopped, the truck just died, and wouldn't start back up.  I opened the hood, and everything was totally dry. Even my patch spot.  The entire exterior of the radiator was dry, and it even had fluid in overflow clear tank.  However, when I opened the radiator cap and looked inside, it was bone dry! There was no liquid in the radiator at all.  I filled it up again, but the truck won't start. It shakes and runs what little I can get out of it.

Any help suggestions pointers or info would be a blessing, as this is our only family vehicle which my family relies on more then anything. I'm a fresh home navy veteran and I'm trying to adjust back into daily living, and in need of little guidance to fix this problem so I can be the husband, father, and provider that I need to be.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your service and welcome to the site. It sounds to me like your truck has overheated and badly warped the head(s) and/or blown head gasket(s) on it. This is major surgery which will incur quite a bit of work to get it done.

Comment: Thank u 1st off for your answer 2nd is there anyway I could tell 4 sure that's what it is sir or any pointers u might could relay that might benefit me at this stage. Again thank u so very much for taking time to answer my ?. Or any tricks or should I say "bandaids" I might could do to buy me a little more time sir

Comment: It's hard to tell the exact extent of the damage. I'm thinking the damage could have been done prior to your repair on the radiator in the first place. Your best bet is to get it looked at, because diagnosis at this stage beyond what I've told you is going to be pretty difficult. Your description tells me there's some major damage and this is the most likely culprit. I don't think there are going to be any bandaids, unfortunately. If you don't want to pay for the work, you next best option may be to buy a used engine, which would be much cheaper, especially if you can do it yourself.

Comment: PS: We're here to help ... you don't have to call me sir ... I was enlisted way too long, lol! Nobody else here is looking for it either, but I appreciate the respect.

Comment: Does/did the exhaust make white clouds?  Pull the dipstick, is it a clear brownish oil color, or like a chocolate milkshake?  These are some simple tests to do, unfortunately either one affirmative spells doom.  Welcome home no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) check your oil. If there is water that will be an indication of an intake gasket or head gasket.

I'll update this after you've relied with that. :)

Thanks for your service! :D and welcome!